# Webworker return result after callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, web-worker

I have an Angular service where I'm using `$q` service in combination with webworkers. In my original function before using webworkers, my `completeClass` function would return an object.

I replaced the code to post a message to my new web worker script.
The callback of the webworker is in my `initWorkers` function where I add the eventlistener.

My goal is that the `completeClass` function returns the result of the webworker. How can I make this happen?

```
this.classWorker = new Worker('app/shared/autocomplete/autocomplete-class-worker.js');

this.completeClass = function(text){
    var self = this;    
    var defer = $q.defer();
    classWorker.postMessage([text, this.oldText, this.oldProposals, this.aliases, this.entityClasses])
};

this.initWorkers = function(){
    var self = this;
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        defer.resolve(e.data);
        self.oldProposals = e.data[1];
        self.oldText = text;
        return e.data[0];
    }, false);
};
```

Comment: You mean you want to return a promise for the result? If you wouldn't be doing it asynchronously, using a webworker wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: All of `worker`, `defer` and `text` are undefined in your `initWorkers` method, and you cannot `return` from event callbacks either.

Comment: @Bergi the problem was that the 'CompleteClass' function was too CPU intensive so I moved it to a webworker so that it runs on a seperate thread. Once it is complete I want to return the result. So yes it runs asynchronously. I'm a bit lost with all the terms regarding 'defer' , 'promise' and 'resolve' though so I'm not sure what I need.

Comment: @Bergi I used to have the addEventListener in my completeClass function, but then it would add the listener each time I call the function

Comment: Are you going to call the function multiple times? Even multiple times while the previous result might not yet have returned? Then it's going to get much more complicated anyway.

Comment: Yes multiple times while the previous one is still running

Comment: OK, in that case you'll need a stream buffer to chain the requests and responses. Manage them as a queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to call the worker when the previous call is still running, then you need something to either queue or keep track of in-progress requests. My suspicion is that unless you need control of the queue of requests, it's simpler for UI thread to fire off the requests to the worker, so the browser essentially queues the requests for you.

But you would still need to keep track of the requests sent somehow, so when you get a message back from the worker, you know which one it is responding do. You can do this by, in the main thread

- Generating a unique ID for each request. An ever-increasing integer can be enough for a lot of cases.
- Creating a deferred object and storing it, associated with the ID
- Firing off the request to the worker, passing the ID
- Passing a the promise of the deferred object back to the caller

The worker then

- Receives the message, with the ID
- Does its' work
- Posts the result back, along with the ID

The main thread then

- Receives the message, with the ID and result of the work.
- Retrieves the deferred object by the ID, and resolves it with the results of the work.

To do this, you can use some code like below. I've slightly simplified your case by passing just `text` to the worker, getting `completeText` back. You can add more information going either way in a real case.

```
app.service('AutoComplete', function($q) {
  var id = 0;
  var worker = new Worker('app/shared/autocomplete/autocomplete-class-worker.js');
  var inProgress = {};

  this.completeClass = function(text) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    id++;
    var request = {
      id: id,
      text: text
    };
    inProgress[id] = deferred;
    worker.postMessage(request);
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    var response = e.data;
    var id = response.id;
    var type = response.type; // resolve, reject, or notify
    var completeText = response.completeText;
    inProgress[id][type](completeText);
    if (type === 'resolve' || type === 'reject') {
      delete inProgress[id];
    }
  };
});
```

Then in the worker you can have code like:

```
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  var request = e.data;
  var text = request.text;
  var id = request.id;

  // Do the work here
  var completeText = ...

  var response = {
    id: id,
    type: 'resolve', // Can reject the promise in the main thread if desired
    completeText: completeText
  };

  self.postMessage(response);
};
```

> My goal is that the completeClass function returns the result of the webworker. How can I make this happen?

To clarify, it can't directly return the result, because the result is calculated asynchronously, and all function calls must return synchronously. But it can return a promise that resolves to the result later, just like `$http` does for example. To use the above, you can do something like

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, AutoComplete) {
   $scope.complete = function(text) {
     AutoComplete.completeClass(text).then(function(result) {
       // Do something with result
     });
   });
});
```

---

Note: technically, passing an ID along with each request isn't necessary if the worker does all its' work synchronously on one request, and so responds to each call in the order received. In the above example, the main thread can always assume the calls to the worker make a first-in-first-out queue. However, passing an ID gives the flexibility of the worker not finishing the work in the order received. Say in a later version it needs to do something asynchronous, like call another worker, or make an ajax request, this method will allow that.