# Using async function to stockfish postMessage

Tags: javascript

I tried working with `stockfish.js` and I have this one problem. I also used `@ninjapixel/chess` for easier `methods` than the original.

```
(async function() {
    console.log('test1`');
    console.log(chess.ascii());
    await stockfish.postMessage('go depth 15');
    console.log(chess.ascii()); // this should change, but it doesn't
    console.log('test2');
})();
```

Why does the `async function` with `await keyword` didn't work?
Why did the `test2` was logged first before the `test3` since I'm using an async function, it should work, but it didn't, why is that?

Here's how I handled `onmessage`:

```
stockfish.onmessage = (e) => {
    let info = e.data ? e.data : e;
    if (info.includes('bestmove') || info.includes('ponder')) {
        const bestmove = info.split(/ +/)[1];
        const ponder = info.split(/ +/)[3];
        chess.move(bestmove, {
            promotion: 'q',
            sloppy: true
        });
        // test2 was logged first before this
        console.log('test3'); // ascii worked in this part
        stockfish.postMessage(`position fen ${chess.fen()}`); // update fen of stockfish
    }
};
```

If there's no way to solve this then should I actually depend on the `onmessage` respond? Because what I wanna do is after I do `postMessage` I want to actually respond after the postMessage NOT directly inside the `onmessage` response.

Like something this:

```
let bestMove = null;
stockfish.onmessage = (e) => {
  let info = e.data ? e.data : e;
  if (info.includes('bestmove') || info.includes('ponder')) {
        bestMove = info.split(/ +/)[1];
        // set bestmove after calculating...
    }
}


(async function() {
  await stockfish.postMessage('go depth 15');
  // do the move after the message
  chess.move(bestMove);
  await stockfish.postMessage(`position fen ${chess.fen()}`);
})();
```

Comment: the code seems correct for async and await, it must be working

Comment: that should work, please create a [mcve]

Comment: what is that `stockfish` object, can you provide a link to documentation? Does its `.postMessage()` method return a promise?

Comment: I used this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/stockfish. I'm not really that sure tho if it supports promises, I haven't read it yet.

Comment: @JamesUrian So you're using it in a web worker? No, these do not support promises, you will have to wait for the message events yourself. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57495988/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33523613/1048572)

Comment: Is there a way then to download stockfishjs without nodejs? I tried installing the stockfishjs from [github](https://github.com/nmrugg/stockfish.js) and it just giving me erros after I reference the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await keyword`, didn't have any effect in your code because the function stockfish.postMessage doesn't return a Promise. postMessage emits an event that will be processed in the next tick. This is why `console.log('test3')` was logged after `console.log('test2')`. After emitting the event it will return synchronously, logging console.log('test2').

stockfish.onmessage will need to be the control centre of all events. It will need to understand the different messages, and do the appropiate actions. You dont need to put the implemention of the actions in the onmessage. You can create a function and called it from stockfish.onmessage... and then inside the action function you could call to stockfish.postMessage if you need to notify stockfis of a change... and so on.... and on...